# XmlnsDefinition in a managed C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, xaml

We have a managed dll that implements a public ref class derived from HwndHost in a Cpp namespace. 
We build a x86 version named mydll10.dll and a x64 version named mydll10_x64.dll. 
We are using the Cpp namespace in a WPF application in the xaml page. We are able to add the proper reference in the project using  '$(Platform)'  conditions.
But we should use in the same page both 
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Cpp;assembly=UvpProInspectWpf10" for the x86 and xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Cpp;assembly=UvpProInspectWpf10_x64" for the x64 exe. 
It is no possible to use any sort of #if #then #else in the xaml.

If the Cpp namespace would be in a C# project, a solution could be in the write

```
`myurl:"http://schemas.me.com/wpf/"
#if x64
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition(myurl, "UvpProInspectWpf10_x64")]
#else
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition(myurl, "UvpProInspectWpf10")]
#endif
```

Assembly.cs file and define

```
xmlns:c=" http://schemas.me.com/wpf/”
```

in the xaml.
I cannot find how to do these assembly definitions in the managed C++ project.
Is this possible?
Of course we could break our naming rules…
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.
Add a reference to System.Xaml.dll to the C++ managed project.
Add an AssemblyInfo.cpp file with

```
using namespace System::Windows::Markup;
[assembly:XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.me.com/wpf/", "Cpp")];
```

Then you can use in the xaml page

```
xmlns:c=" http://schemas.me.com/wpf/”
```

with the project referring to the proper x86 or x64 version